# Bootstrap carousel controls outside responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

can you help me how to fix this issue with responsiveness of bootstrap carousel controls (arrow left and right) which are absolutely positioned outside of the container and carouse inner?

Why outside? I have psd design, and arrows are positioned and drawn outside of the container (1170px)

This is my current code. http://www.bootply.com/7QYYKSbZFS

You'll noticed when you test under different screen resolution (mobile, tablet and pc), appears horizontal scroll, which is not good.

Can you please help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: edit your question and hit CTRL + M and put all of your code into that snippet box that opens

Comment: anyone, please?

Comment: I've noticed you use a -7.5% for the left and right carousel controls; which causes the horizontal scroll to appear, if you remove them, the horizontal scroll dissappears and they move closer towards the content which you obviously do not want - hence the -7.5. However, you could play around with media queries to get what you want: @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) and (max-width: @screen-md-max) { ... }, check http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Comment: ok, this is good for resolutions 1200px, 992px and 768px (right in pixel), but when I start shrinking resolution more, horizontal scroll appears again.